# C++ Have class function pass reference to class itself?

Tags: c++, function, reference

Basically, I have a `class World` that contains all the data relevant to the game state for my game. This class has functions like `getPlayerPosition()` and `hasLeader()`, and it also has access to the location of every drawable object in the game.

Inside of `world.update()` I have an FSM of sorts running. I'll spare the details, but essentially I have another object that has a function called `test(World& world, SceneNode& node)` that takes a reference of the World so that it can test things like some node's distance from player. I have many of these "conditional" objects that do different things, so they each need access to different parts of World, which is why I pass in the World&.

But `world.update()` calls this test function! Can I get world to pass a reference of itself? In another build of this project I think we tried passing `(*this)`, but we were getting SegFaults and my partner believes it is because of `(*this)`

Comment: `*this` will never produce a segfault. That is nonsensical as it would involve a function being called from the context of an invalid object!

Comment: Find another partner.

Comment: @Jefffrey I don't blame him, we are both c++ beginners and we could not, for the life of us, figure out how our program was crashing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*this will not cause segment fault. But if your `test()` invokes `world.xxx()` functions, and `xxx()` may invoke `test()`, then you get a recursion. If this is the case, it causes stack overflow and segment fault may occur.